# What is a console application naming convention for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I develop Visual Studio solutions I like to use naming conventions for the projects based on the project type.

For example:
MyProject.UI.Windows,
MyProject.UI.Mobile,
MyProject.Library

I am wondering what to call console applications. I'm thinking about "MyProject.CommandLine" but it seems a bit wordy. What is a console application naming convention for Visual Studio?

Comment: Instead of what it *is* maybe name what it *does*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116178/naming-main-assembly-exe-to-avoid-long-file-name-company-product-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629531/console-application-structure

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It really depends on what the command line app *does*, not just the fact that it is a command line app.  Here's a list I came up with when I was grappling with this same question:

> - Daemon
> - Client
> - Agent
> - Service
> - Utility/Util
> - Host
> - Application/App
> - Library
> - Runner/Launcher
> - Helper
> - Config
> - Console
> - Handler
> - Converter
> - Manager
> - Controller
> - Generator
> - Editor
> - Viewer
> - Logger
> - Proxy
> - Program
> - Script/Scriptable